# Bringing laptop to the US

Tags: air-travel

Recently it's been in the news that the US were going to ban laptops on flights to the US. Now I am not sure if this really happened or not, so I was hoping someone was.

I'm not sure if this makes a difference, but I go to the US, and at some point I have a domestic flight there too.

EDIT: I am from the Netherlands

Comment: As far as I have understood (but I'm not sure I'm up-to-date) they have currently only banned laptops if you're travelling from specific countries, and as you haven't said where you're from, we can't say if it affects you.

Comment: Netherlands is not one of the countries with the ban, though it's about the origin of the flight, not the origin of the person.

Comment: I'll have lay-over in Iceland, which isn't part of the ban either right? Dorothy might be right that this is a duplicate, I'll turn to the other thread from now.

Comment: @Dorothy The linked question is closed as a duplicate of a question closed for being unclear. Shouldn't the "duplicate trail" lead to something less of a dead end? (And why should there be a trail longer than one step in the first place?)

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta true, but it actually has an answer which IMO responds to this one more closely than what it was duped to; go figure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on the Airport of your departure or layover. The US government has disallowed to bring any electronic devices larger than a smartphone (no cameras, tablets, game consoles, and laptops) into your hand luggage inside a plane. The rules only apply for flights to the US from these airports:

- <strike>Jordan Queen Alia International</strike> *([cleared <= 2017-07-18](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2017/07/18/us_laptops_in_plane_cabins_ban_close_to_end/))*
- <strike>Egypt Cairo International</strike> *(cleared <= 2017-07-18)*
- <strike>Turkey Istanbul Ataturk</strike> *([Turkish Airlines cleared 2017-07-05?](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-40504049))*
- <strike>Saudi Arabia King Abdulaziz International</strike> *(cleared <= 2017-07-18)*
- Saudi Arabia King Khalid International
- <strike>Kuwait International</strike> *(cleared <= 2017-07-18)*
- <strike>Qatar Doha International</strike> *([cleared 2017-07-06](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-usa-airlines-electronics-idUSKBN19R07C))*
- <strike>Morocco Mohammed V Airport</strike> *(cleared <= 2017-07-18)*
- <strike>Dubai International</strike> *(cleared <= 2017-07-18)*
- <strike>Abu Dabi International</strike> *([cleared 2017-07-02](http://www.independent.co.uk/travel/news-and-advice/abu-dhabi-airport-laptop-ban-lifted-etihad-electronics-donald-trump-a7819641.html))*

You should keep in mind. That if you have a layover in the airports from the list you also won't be able to bring such electronics into the plane. (For example, if you flying from Amsterdam to New York with Turkish Airlines through Istanbul).

You are still allowed to bring such electronics in the checked in baggage.

Comment: Did they clear the airports or specific airlines?

Comment: The ban only applied to non-US carriers and direct flights, which I believe in this case makes the carrier unique to the airport. That is, only the foreign national carrier flies the route direct anyway. Hence whether the carrier or the airport is cleared is not critical.

Comment: But if you flying from London with layover you can finish on the direct flight with such strict rules. The situation my go worse as you would not be able to add something to your luggage during layover stop, while laptop was allowed on the first leg. If you have layover in the airport in the list, I will recommend to contact your airline for clarification.