# Can I bring a laptop on board a Turkish flight to the US having a connection in Istanbul?

Tags: usa, hand-luggage, electronic-items, istanbul, turkish-airlines

I apologize for asking a question similar to previously asked questions (such as [this one](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/96565/bringing-laptop-to-the-us/96569#96569)), but I've seen conflicting statements on the matter, and wanted to learn from first hand experience.

I've seen a report from 5 July 2017 that [US laptop ban lifted on Emirates and Turkish Airlines](http://www.bbc.com/news/business-40504049):

> Turkish Airlines said it was also now allowing passengers travelling to the US to take their laptops onboard.

However, I just booked a Turkish Airlines flight from Israel to the US via Istanbul, and got the following message in the confirmation email:

> **New Cabin Device Rules**
>
> Please be aware of the new cabin device rules on your flight.
>
> Under the new rules, all electronic devices larger than 16cm long, 9.3 wide or 1.5cm deep, must be packed into luggage going into the hold. They are no longer allowed in the cabin.

Which of these two statements correct? I rather not check-in my laptop, since checked luggage has a risk of being lost.

Has anyone recently boarded a Turkish Airlines flight in Istanbul and was able to take a laptop on board?

Comment: It’s not an outdated rule. They changed them again. Call Turkish Airlines to check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The laptop rules were indeed revoked around the middle of 2017.  I have flown Turkish to the US multiple times since they were revoked and there has been no need to check large electronics devices.

The email you have received from Turkish Airlines is outdated.  Given how poor their IT systems apparently are, this does not surprise me.  (Try using their new website to do anything and you'll know what I mean...)

Note that even when there was a need to check such devices, you did not need to put them in your checked luggage.  Turkish Airlines was collecting these devices in the gate/boarding area and placing them in a protective/secure case that went into the hold, with the devices being retrieved in the baggage area at the destination airport.